# Adding user contributed code to repository under GNU GPL 3.0 License

Tags: gpl-3

I have a project that I created and released under the GNU GPL License v3.0. Today a user of the software contacted me and presented me with a list of improvements and the code necessary to implement them. If I want to add these modifications to the source code in the next release, how do I legally and fairly recognize his contribution in doing so? Am I allowed to release the project with his modified code?

In my naiveté, it seems to me as though I would be licensing the software to him, and he would be licensing the modified licensed software back to me... kinda' circular.

Thank you in advance and thank you especially for your patience!

Comment: Which bit of the GPL are you finding it hard to interpret as to what you need to do? Section 5 is, while a bit wordy, pretty clear on this IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have created a work *de novo* and made it available to the world under GPLv3, being the sole rightsholder therein.  Someone has taken it and made a modified version, which they have chosen to convey back to you, also under GPLv3 (as they must).  You and this contributor are both rightsholders in the modified version.

The contributor is obliged by GPLv3 s5a to add "*prominent notices stating that [they] modified it, and giving a relevant date*", the usual form of which are copyright notices added to your own, thus reading eg (in the files (s)he has modified):

```
(c) 2020-2022 H. Airbrain
(c) 2022 A. Contributor
```

You certainly may incorporate his/her changes into your project for its next release.  You should retain his/her new copyright notices, and that is the extent to which his/her contribution must, and is expected to, be recognised.

I note in passing that as you are no longer the sole rightsholder in this codebase, you may no longer unilaterally decide to relicense it.

Comment: That actually works out very well. I'll always keep it open source so it doesn't pose any problems. Thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: @hairbrain you're very welcome, thank you for the acceptance (the green tick), and welcome to OS.SE!

Comment: Keeping it open source does not suffice. Keeping it gplv3 is required, if initially conveyed as such

Comment: @planetmaker I hoped I'd made that point when I said that the OP could no longer unilaterally relicense - but it's always worth making a second time.  Thank you!

Comment: I agree that you did. My comment was more in reply to the OP's comment here. Keeping it open-source does not suffice when choosing GPL. There does not remain much choice than keeping it GPL.

Answer (score -1):

The relevant question is, under which license they provided their code.

They may implicitly have provided it under the license of the project, but this may be not that clear and unclarity may result in legal problems. Very minor corrections may not have a copyright at all, e.g., when someone points out a typo there is probably not much to do.

The other answer explains how to add the code when it is GPL (compatible) licensed.

---

In theory someone could send a patch without any license (thus not granting the right to use it at all) or with an incompatible license, their code is at first just a piece of text that is copyrighted by them. Using it together with your code may be prohibited in this case, what would make it mostly useless.

Useful licenses for them would include GPLv3 and compatible. They can, for example, decide to make it available under BSDL. This would mean, that the combination of your product and their code would only be usable under GPL, but their code alone can be used together with other projects without the restrictions imposed by the GPL.

Another interesting aspect is, that the GPL is about distribution. Even when the code may not be distributed together with your product, you (and they) can use the combined product yourself as long as you do not distribute it.

---

That's the theory. Now for the practical aspect: Ask them to tell you under which license it can be used and suggest to use a GPLv3 compatible one explaining that you otherwise cannot include it into the product.

---

From the discussion: A simple case in which a patch may have an unclear, more permissive, or more prohibitive license would be that your GPLed program is a fork of a BSDL program.

Now I may have written a patch that applies to the BSDL program and can be used with your GPLed program as well because let's say it did not modify that file after the fork.

Following the BSDL, I can both have my patch BSDL, and you can still add it to your program or have it under a proprietary license that still follows the BSDL terms. The BSDL does not prohibit the use in proprietary codes but only has some less restrictive requirements like crediting the authors. (Read the license for full details)

In the second case, you're not allowed to combine it with your code. Combining it with the pre-fork code would probably make the derived work licensed under my proprietary license or just be disallowed, depending on the terms of my more restrictive license.

---

So the final recommendation is: *Make sure to have people tell you how their code can be used.*

In most cases, it will be something like "It can be used under your project's license" or "You are free to use it however you like" anyway.

Comment: Any patch submitted to a GPL work **must** itself be under the GPL; otherwise, as a derivative work, the patch could not lawfully be distributed at all.  In the absence of a clear statement of intent to the contrary, the mere act of distribution is a clear sign of the distributor's acceptance of the GPL.

Comment: @MadHatter you're missing the point here. Let's assume a patch format that does not contain a "negated" copy of the removed original code, like `remove 3-12;insert "some new code" at 17`. Then the patch without context is just a piece of text that is copyrighted by me. The derived work results from applying the patch and is not the patch itself. And you shouldn't just assume acceptance as it may put you at legal risk. Ask when it is unclear. And I am always free to choose a more liberal GPL-compatible license.

Comment: I can't agree.  The patch was still developed very much in the context of the original work, as a result of detailed scrutiny thereof and with the specific intention of being therein inserted, and is therefore, to my mind, a derivative of it.

Comment: I see your point, why it is derived. But then we're at the question of whether someone can prove it is derived and if it makes a difference. Is the silence derived from [John Cage's 4′33″](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%B233%E2%80%B3)? It may be, and then it would be a derived work. Or it is not. The second of silence itself does not contain any since if it is derived work. In the same way, I could apply my patch that removes lines 3 to 12 and inserts a new line at line 17 to many different codes. The result will not always make sense, but sense is not required for having the copyright.

Comment: The two examples are fundamentally different.  One could come up with a second of silence without ever having heard, or heard of, Cage's work.  It is not credible to claim you came up with a functional patch without deep study of the original program.

Comment: One should also not forget the possibility that the patch itself is a copyright violation of someone's else copyright. Again, this would be a patch that cannot be assumed to be GPL licensed because it is (also) derived from your work. And there are many ways to have patches that work on many works. Just think of a little logo bitmap that is to be added to the top-left corner of an image. The logo can be applied to *any* image larger than the logo itself. Still, it needs to have the correct license for you to be allowed to combine it with your image.

Comment: Or yet another example: Your GPL program is a re-licensed fork of a BSDL program, and the patch applies cleanly to both programs. Then the patch can have a proprietary license that allows it to be combined with the BSDL program but prevents it from being applied to your GPLed fork.

Comment: There are now two issues: one is the implicit licence on a properly-contributed patch to a GPL work, the second is whether a particular contributor has any right to contribute a particular patch.  That second one is a very real issue, which many projects are addressing with (eg) [DCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developer_Certificate_of_Origin)s - but it is orthogonal to the first issue.  I stand by my position on the first issue, and don't think it will be helpful to discuss it further here; the second isn't this question at all, and should probably also be taken no further here.

Comment: Indeed. I think my answer contains the important parts and you can add an own answer and downvote mine. I may edit some parts later if I find how to make it more clear.